# Finding Count Sum in Array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, binning

I've been struggling with this code for a couple hours and need some guidance. I have a list of 500 numbers and I need to get the count of how many numbers are between 150 and 200.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 500
int main()
{
float a[N]={133.077, 353.171, 272.317, 9.84711, 100.156, 468.909, 127.629,
1.25313, 331.166, 12.4806, 47.1308, 459.066, 222.106, 320.366,
447.939, 315.992, 368.533, 488.7, 316.918, 201.467, 61.2842, 356.199,
131.416, 110.222, 428.207, 4.02826, 359.1, 101.375, 329.052, 35.1193,
232.471, 101.122, 497.885, 23.6387, 186.34, 142.056, 276.78, 203.273,
238.401, 326.064, 408.247, 214.573, 421.483, 125.597, 347.963,
358.374, 291.067, 16.3751, 419.756, 355.345, 431.967, 415., 91.7042,
321.226, 200.497, 314.879, 93.8189, 298.587, 15.1569, 173.822,
317.039, 96.3144, 276.756, 347.759, 408.792, 381.742, 355.273,
223.162, 61.8293, 24.3681, 65.2061, 207.787, 142.073, 169.023,
133.239, 292.786, 51.3692, 347.797, 432.742, 477.908, 457.55,
50.2092, 418.585, 305.085, 141.511, 453.895, 142.829, 457.327,
232.719, 73.1532, 287.556, 235.165, 171.89, 49.7851, 223.35, 28.3785,
30.8162, 380.762, 91.111, 235.592, 479.447, 33.9658, 158.369,
257.684, 22.8966, 483.757, 239.784, 452.599, 381.386, 30.8617,
97.9551, 495.273, 149.667, 457.709, 310.399, 261.108, 477.777,
408.923, 88.0496, 233.729, 447.961, 29.1611, 496.939, 498.137,
468.514, 495.195, 339.569, 241.452, 446.617, 12.4387, 100.785,
288.853, 66.2314, 481.577, 3.83027, 293.581, 416.565, 24.8685,
193.431, 33.4731, 438.788, 115.945, 106.381, 299.744, 490.828,
87.784, 109.443, 301.607, 23.314, 92.5887, 269.873, 61.155, 76.6971,
81.15, 170.088, 272.302, 11.4657, 99.5729, 167.258, 478.721, 94.9008,
75.7044, 473.827, 446.248, 156.113, 459.759, 368.445, 147.504,
165.285, 372.975, 260.003, 345.897, 142.971, 281.387, 490.129,
285.742, 67.274, 201.237, 321.041, 14.4398, 56.8083, 102.664,
154.783, 35.7185, 461.908, 27.9593, 180.957, 89.4704, 306.795,
68.1999, 312.511, 441.966, 142.51, 195.225, 53.5086, 97.0697,
499.538, 413.838, 63.3795, 311.328, 433.264, 213.601, 242.338,
297.888, 377.456, 111.938, 88.5552, 263.17, 415.549, 84.9783,
407.599, 174.699, 109.754, 17.7784, 96.0876, 232.733, 467.244,
322.554, 43.579, 136.663, 467.706, 408.716, 480.199, 325.335,
35.4412, 196.114, 238.861, 28.4469, 157.985, 85.1769, 151.306,
265.277, 242.437, 1.19858, 243.707, 91.5778, 133.683, 483.42,
148.619, 358.845, 166.439, 161.866, 106.04, 223.182, 198.733,
253.151, 125.841, 397.846, 164.292, 58.0362, 386.98, 370.4, 7.30672,
472.859, 236.674, 106.122, 264.87, 472.661, 492.967, 15.5447,
132.187, 489.24, 345.348, 156.7, 465.749, 328.374, 240.307, 433.518,
268.016, 76.2234, 115.466, 36.6719, 104.724, 19.1872, 228.486,
166.272, 98.4171, 46.328, 491.812, 61.1499, 333.547, 73.6673,
498.844, 46.6052, 202.36, 84.4268, 154.496, 389.905, 236.611,
256.053, 414.189, 456.387, 468.595, 180.829, 299.723, 420.715,
364.871, 162.642, 72.2363, 255.443, 267.454, 117.314, 80.4245,
195.293, 433.907, 44.6469, 81.58, 149.688, 232.548, 460.22, 427.084,
259.782, 495.937, 205.167, 13.8946, 303.395, 28.3416, 25.3379,
214.172, 382.68, 163.47, 362.696, 142.936, 128.237, 396.016, 246.382,
63.5113, 432.945, 462.109, 202.735, 481.931, 284.257, 230.561,
242.515, 55.8477, 25.4743, 234.624, 38.3473, 42.9531, 222.079,
207.283, 14.0094, 328.781, 339.399, 44.8123, 151.314, 186.845,
212.161, 148.796, 404.932, 124.334, 279.217, 186.688, 203.197,
142.403, 494.96, 456.127, 460.683, 87.5551, 470.486, 222.503,
423.336, 45.602, 249.407, 16.22, 410.326, 216.821, 410.008, 471.408,
260.013, 30.9757, 198.847, 323.611, 355.081, 406.642, 419.63,
137.924, 152.883, 265.239, 424.67, 181.797, 192.2, 178.684, 454.185,
459.295, 268.865, 134.082, 205.778, 444.075, 358.539, 417.261,
295.77, 472.667, 99.5259, 387.285, 97.9232, 150.056, 244.445,
480.643, 178.293, 13.1318, 92.5622, 216.404, 253.623, 331.335,
400.362, 38.7207, 299.438, 372.04, 132.497, 404.639, 94.6604,
427.966, 273.959, 487.378, 298.89, 455.299, 175.433, 101.093,
201.967, 306.243, 430.987, 120.45, 24.6742, 294.111, 339.425,
404.045, 271.051, 462.777, 439.063, 366.325, 471.613, 91.7363,
307.566, 461.686, 377.953, 163.771, 34.6073, 474.307, 80.0622,
208.472, 359.175, 374.214, 378.095, 402.229, 428.187, 254.764,
354.421, 109.117, 89.762, 350.719, 84.3694, 146.341, 150.699,
484.394, 112.756, 55.6046, 343.133, 23.7084, 234.804, 391.834,
309.526, 49.4009, 155.742, 184.362, 450.351, 175.187, 277.647,
282.133, 23.1639, 420.422, 423.226, 174.016, 433.402, 70.7036,
339.857, 28.6748, 283.703, 86.3095, 228.1, 473.07, 440.57, 63.6011,
493.296, 82.2363, 132.045, 15.2001, 338.555, 397.874, 181.694,
340.013, 61.9079, 116.741, 159.53, 419.591, 138.682, 442.725,
226.128, 349.887, 298.825};
```

At this point I am lost. I am trying to think of how to set up a program with a counter to count all values of 150 < N < 200. I think this is the right idea to solve this problem, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
int count = 0;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if ((a[i] >= 150.0) && (a[i] <= 200.0)) {
        ++count;
    }
}

printf("The number of values between 150 and 200 (inclusive) are: %d\n", count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int i, count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    if(a[i] > 150.0 && a[i] < 200.0){count++;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your closing brace, and the rest out your code should look something like this

```
int i;
int count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if (a[i] >=150 && a[i] <= 200) count++;
}
printf("%i\n", count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 500

#define LowerLimit 150.0
#define UpperLimit 200.0
int main()
{
float a[N]={133.077, 353.171, 272.317, 9.84711, 100.156, 468.909, 127.629,
1.25313, 331.166, 12.4806, 47.1308, 459.066, 222.106, 320.366,
447.939, 315.992, 368.533, 488.7, 316.918, 201.467, 61.2842, 356.199,
131.416, 110.222, 428.207, 4.02826, 359.1, 101.375, 329.052, 35.1193,
232.471, 101.122, 497.885, 23.6387, 186.34, 142.056, 276.78, 203.273,
238.401, 326.064, 408.247, 214.573, 421.483, 125.597, 347.963,
358.374, 291.067, 16.3751, 419.756, 355.345, 431.967, 415., 91.7042,
321.226, 200.497, 314.879, 93.8189, 298.587, 15.1569, 173.822,
317.039, 96.3144, 276.756, 347.759, 408.792, 381.742, 355.273,
223.162, 61.8293, 24.3681, 65.2061, 207.787, 142.073, 169.023,
133.239, 292.786, 51.3692, 347.797, 432.742, 477.908, 457.55,
50.2092, 418.585, 305.085, 141.511, 453.895, 142.829, 457.327,
232.719, 73.1532, 287.556, 235.165, 171.89, 49.7851, 223.35, 28.3785,
30.8162, 380.762, 91.111, 235.592, 479.447, 33.9658, 158.369,
257.684, 22.8966, 483.757, 239.784, 452.599, 381.386, 30.8617,
97.9551, 495.273, 149.667, 457.709, 310.399, 261.108, 477.777,
408.923, 88.0496, 233.729, 447.961, 29.1611, 496.939, 498.137,
468.514, 495.195, 339.569, 241.452, 446.617, 12.4387, 100.785,
288.853, 66.2314, 481.577, 3.83027, 293.581, 416.565, 24.8685,
193.431, 33.4731, 438.788, 115.945, 106.381, 299.744, 490.828,
87.784, 109.443, 301.607, 23.314, 92.5887, 269.873, 61.155, 76.6971,
81.15, 170.088, 272.302, 11.4657, 99.5729, 167.258, 478.721, 94.9008,
75.7044, 473.827, 446.248, 156.113, 459.759, 368.445, 147.504,
165.285, 372.975, 260.003, 345.897, 142.971, 281.387, 490.129,
285.742, 67.274, 201.237, 321.041, 14.4398, 56.8083, 102.664,
154.783, 35.7185, 461.908, 27.9593, 180.957, 89.4704, 306.795,
68.1999, 312.511, 441.966, 142.51, 195.225, 53.5086, 97.0697,
499.538, 413.838, 63.3795, 311.328, 433.264, 213.601, 242.338,
297.888, 377.456, 111.938, 88.5552, 263.17, 415.549, 84.9783,
407.599, 174.699, 109.754, 17.7784, 96.0876, 232.733, 467.244,
322.554, 43.579, 136.663, 467.706, 408.716, 480.199, 325.335,
35.4412, 196.114, 238.861, 28.4469, 157.985, 85.1769, 151.306,
265.277, 242.437, 1.19858, 243.707, 91.5778, 133.683, 483.42,
148.619, 358.845, 166.439, 161.866, 106.04, 223.182, 198.733,
253.151, 125.841, 397.846, 164.292, 58.0362, 386.98, 370.4, 7.30672,
472.859, 236.674, 106.122, 264.87, 472.661, 492.967, 15.5447,
132.187, 489.24, 345.348, 156.7, 465.749, 328.374, 240.307, 433.518,
268.016, 76.2234, 115.466, 36.6719, 104.724, 19.1872, 228.486,
166.272, 98.4171, 46.328, 491.812, 61.1499, 333.547, 73.6673,
498.844, 46.6052, 202.36, 84.4268, 154.496, 389.905, 236.611,
256.053, 414.189, 456.387, 468.595, 180.829, 299.723, 420.715,
364.871, 162.642, 72.2363, 255.443, 267.454, 117.314, 80.4245,
195.293, 433.907, 44.6469, 81.58, 149.688, 232.548, 460.22, 427.084,
259.782, 495.937, 205.167, 13.8946, 303.395, 28.3416, 25.3379,
214.172, 382.68, 163.47, 362.696, 142.936, 128.237, 396.016, 246.382,
63.5113, 432.945, 462.109, 202.735, 481.931, 284.257, 230.561,
242.515, 55.8477, 25.4743, 234.624, 38.3473, 42.9531, 222.079,
207.283, 14.0094, 328.781, 339.399, 44.8123, 151.314, 186.845,
212.161, 148.796, 404.932, 124.334, 279.217, 186.688, 203.197,
142.403, 494.96, 456.127, 460.683, 87.5551, 470.486, 222.503,
423.336, 45.602, 249.407, 16.22, 410.326, 216.821, 410.008, 471.408,
260.013, 30.9757, 198.847, 323.611, 355.081, 406.642, 419.63,
137.924, 152.883, 265.239, 424.67, 181.797, 192.2, 178.684, 454.185,
459.295, 268.865, 134.082, 205.778, 444.075, 358.539, 417.261,
295.77, 472.667, 99.5259, 387.285, 97.9232, 150.056, 244.445,
480.643, 178.293, 13.1318, 92.5622, 216.404, 253.623, 331.335,
400.362, 38.7207, 299.438, 372.04, 132.497, 404.639, 94.6604,
427.966, 273.959, 487.378, 298.89, 455.299, 175.433, 101.093,
201.967, 306.243, 430.987, 120.45, 24.6742, 294.111, 339.425,
404.045, 271.051, 462.777, 439.063, 366.325, 471.613, 91.7363,
307.566, 461.686, 377.953, 163.771, 34.6073, 474.307, 80.0622,
208.472, 359.175, 374.214, 378.095, 402.229, 428.187, 254.764,
354.421, 109.117, 89.762, 350.719, 84.3694, 146.341, 150.699,
484.394, 112.756, 55.6046, 343.133, 23.7084, 234.804, 391.834,
309.526, 49.4009, 155.742, 184.362, 450.351, 175.187, 277.647,
282.133, 23.1639, 420.422, 423.226, 174.016, 433.402, 70.7036,
339.857, 28.6748, 283.703, 86.3095, 228.1, 473.07, 440.57, 63.6011,
493.296, 82.2363, 132.045, 15.2001, 338.555, 397.874, 181.694,
340.013, 61.9079, 116.741, 159.53, 419.591, 138.682, 442.725,
226.128, 349.887, 298.825};

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (a[i] > LowerLimit && a[i] < UpperLimit) {
        count++;
    }
}
printf("Number of elements between %f and %f = %d\n",LowerLimit, UpperLimit, count);
return 0;
}
```